# mysql list of variables with regex

Tags: mysql

My question :

for each of the id in space_id table, i want to get the list of batch id's in batch_ids table

```
space_id table

+-------+
|   id  |
+-------+
| spa_1 |
| spa_2 |
| spa_3 |
| spa_4 |
| spa_5 |
+-------+


batch_ids table

+------------+---------------+
|  batch_id  | request_id    |
+------------+---------------+
| 1          |task_spa_1_task|
| 2          |task_spa_2_task|
| 3          |task_spa_3_task|
| 4          |task_spa_4_task|
| 5          |task_spa_5_task|
| 6          |task_spa_6_task|
| 7          |task_spa_2_task|
| 8          |task_spa_3_task|
| 9          |task_spa_9_task|
|10          |task_spa_8_task|
+------------+---------------+
```

so my expected output should be batch_id = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8]

```
+------------+---------------+
|  batch_id  | request_id    |
+------------+---------------+
| 1          |task_spa_1_task|
| 2          |task_spa_2_task|
| 3          |task_spa_3_task|
| 4          |task_spa_4_task|
| 5          |task_spa_5_task|
| 7          |task_spa_2_task|
| 8          |task_spa_3_task|
+------------+---------------+
```

What i've tried

```
with space_ids AS(
  select id from space_id
)

  select batch_id 
    from batch_ids 
    where request_id  like concat((select id from space_ids), '%')
```

returns me `Single-row subquery returns more than one row.`
I know this is not the right query but any help by mysql gurus would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use group_concat.

```
select group_concat(b.batch_id) as batch_id 
from space_id s 
INNER JOIN batch_ids b ON b.request_id LIKE CONCAT('%',s.id,'%');
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4fb56d2f567792180a3e3250d3a063c5

If you want to include `[` in the result use:

```
select concat('[',group_concat(b.batch_id),']') as batch_id 
from space_id s 
INNER JOIN batch_ids b ON b.request_id LIKE CONCAT('%',s.id,'%');
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=165c3029fc4253a393367cef7f768c89

Comment: does this still hold good?I edited my question

Comment: @sai you can check the fiddle and test with your data, there is no need for with clause. You can try either of the methods, they will give your expected result

Comment: thanks, that worked. you're an SQL god for me